# MS cash drawer with epson TM-IV88 Status API

Tags: point-of-sale, opos, epson, drawer

Does anyone know how to monitor cash drawer's open/close state using Advanced Printer Driver's Status API for Epson TM-88IV thermal printer.

I wish i could use OPOS for ADK .Net, but haven't had luck setting it up on windows 7. Does anyone know how to be a part of epson developer network. I have gone through the information available at www.epson-pos.com but there is no information available on POS/ESC codes.

Please help...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, it took a quite a while to figure out, how to determine cash drawer's Open/Close status using StatusAPI for Epson TM-88IV printer. This field represents the cash drawer closed status.

```
Public Const ASB_DRAWER_KICK As com.epson.pos.driver.ASB = 4
```

According to documentation from epson (rather, according to my understanding of it), 0 represents drawer open and 4 represents drawer closed status. So while monitoring printer status you need to check for this bit.

Comment: Hi, Do you have an example of how to implement this please? I'm trying to monitor the status of the drawer, firing it using esc/pos commands from a C# application.

Answer (score 0):

Try signing up here: https://www.epsonexpert.com/login

That seems to be the place to get technical info about Epson POS products. I can't say if they specifically have what you want. I signed up just now, but now I have to wait for them to get back to me:

> Thank you for registering with
>   EpsonExpert. We have received your
>   registration information and will be
>   contacting you shortly, once your
>   request has been reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different problem. I also have the same printer (TM-T88IV) and a standard cash drawer. I have them set up in SetupPos and CheckHealthTest application works fine for both printer and drawer (the printer prints and the drawer opens). But once I try to run the Epson cash drawer .net sample it throws PosControlException and says "The information is not described in XML". 
Having spent a couple of days trying to find the solution I came nowhere but pulled a couple of thoughts on the issue from several forums. They say that the error is related to the fact that the cash drawer service object is not fully defined in Configuration.xml (Microsoft POS for .net). Also the epson documentation on setting up cash drawers states that if OPOS fails to create the communication class instance it throws an exception. 
I am pretty sure that me being not along in getting across with this problem and would appreciate any useful feedback!
Thanks!

Comment: Solved.

SetupPOS (as well as CheckHealthTest) needs to be launched with admin credentials!!! otherwise it will only save changes to configuration file which is local for the current user!